# Where to put a custom validator in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, registration

I am working on implementing the solution outlined here: [How to use custom password validators beside the django auth password validators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915518/how-to-use-custom-password-validators-beside-the-django-auth-password-validators)

The answer is very helpful except for one aspect: Where do I put the code for the validator?! In AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS I see the line:

```
'NAME': registration.validators.CustomPasswortValidator
```

but how do I put the CustomPasswortValidator method into registration.validators? What even is registration.validators? Where can I find that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The line below:

```
'NAME': 'registration.validators.CustomPasswortValidator'
```

mean that you need to have a **registration app**, and inside that app there is **validators.py file**, and inside that file there is a **method** called **CustomPasswortValidator**.

So, you can work accordingly by giving your own app name, file name and method name.