# Django: Python path syntax to my custom validators.py?

Tags: python, django

I want to implement the solution detailed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915518/how-to-use-custom-password-validators-beside-the-django-auth-password-validators) but I can't for the life of me figure out the Python path syntax in `settings.py` needed to link back to my custom `validators.py` I'm not even sure where to put it. I feel like a simple explanation of how the Python path syntax works in Django ought to be in the docs but after almost 20 minutes of looking through them I don't see anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the paths for validators in `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`?

Comment: Yes; I want to add one I wrote in a script and I don't know a) where it's best to place the script or b) what syntax to use to refer to the script's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your custom `validators.py` is within your project, so like any of your other Python project's module it is accessed using dot notation.

The only thing "different" here is that you append the actual class name to this module string. For example:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    'yourproject.validators.YourValidatorClass',
]
```

(although the format is not specified in this specific setting in the docs, it is a constant pattern used throughout Django settings)

Comment: Can't play around w/ this at the moment because I'm at work but just for clarification: My `validators.py` can be anywhere within my project or should it be in a particular place? Also `yourproject` in your code slice above should be the name at the top of my `settings.py`, correct? Like `Django settings for project_name project`?

Comment: @nicecore usually you'd put it in a relevant place. For example, you may have an app for authentication, it may override some of django or include a `UserProfile` model etc. In that case you'd have something like `authentication.validators.YourValidatorClass`. If you don't have an app like that, just in your project directory.

Comment: @markwalker_ So I noticed in `settings.py` there is a reference to `wsgi.py`, which resides in the same folder as my settings and my `validators.py`, and the path is `project_7.wsgi`. For the base URLs file it's `project_7.urls`. So for the custom validators I have it as `project_7.validators`. All of these are in the same folder yet I still get the error.

Comment: Okay so for some reason putting `validators.py` in an app I have called `accounts` and then in settings putting `'accounts.validators.YourValidatorClass'` worked. Any idea why it wouldn't work if I just had it in the base project file?